# What maths should I learn for game programming, and what aspect of programming does it relate to?

Tags: collision-detection, mathematics, physics, graphics-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What math should all game programmers know?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2029/what-math-should-all-game-programmers-know)

Obviously a good knowledge of maths is essential for good programming, my maths isn’t the best ( I didn’t pay attention in school all those years ago) so, in order to get one step closer to being the best I need some advice. What maths should I learn for specific areas of game programming? 
If someone could outline some subjects and say one or two words about what areas of game programming they would be used in I’d greatly appreciate it. I’m working through the Khan academy programme at the moment, and I’m just getting into algebra now.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, but you can see one math question relevant to the "collision-detection" tag here http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11520/given-a-plane-and-a-point-how-can-i-determine-which-side-of-the-plane-the-point

Comment: noted, sorry for the duplication!

Answer (score 1):

Learn the math as you need it. That's how I did, and it will "save you time". The math needed depends a lot on the game you are making (whether or not it's 2D or 3D, whether or not it has advanced physics, etc etc).