# How can I get the normal vector for a plane from a set of vertices?

Tags: mathematics, vector, geometry, vertex, normals

I'm working on a HLSL / C++ little project to going over my graphics work, and I am unsure how I am to get a facing vector from a vertex polygon. I can't seem to find the formula.

[image]

The positions are P1, P2,P3

Let's call them class VertexPoint with P1.x, P1.y, P1.z for example?

Comment: closely related question: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11520/given-a-plane-and-a-point-how-can-i-determine-which-side-of-the-plane-the-point/

Comment: Just for correctness, the label in the picture and question title should be "**normal vector**" instead of "normalized vector". The normal vector itself can of course be normalized (its length being the unity), but it doesn't need to, and the cross product won't produce a normalized vector by default.

Comment: Googling "normal vector triangle", which is the obvious thing to Google, gives zillions of hits. [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305642/how-to-find-surface-normal-of-a-triangle), [2](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Calculating_a_Surface_Normal), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350792/calculate-normal-of-a-single-triangle-in-3d-space), [4](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/24132.aspx), [5](https://www.tjhsst.edu/~dhyatt/supercomp/n310.html), [6](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/167145-Triangle-Normal-Calculation), ...

Comment: ... [7](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-do-i-get-the-normal-of-each-triangle-in-mesh.101018/), [8](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ComputingNormalPerpendicularVector.html), [9](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ComputingNormalPerpendicularVector.html), [10](http://www.kev.pulo.com.au/sv3/sv3_1999_assignment2/node21.html), [11](http://www.kev.pulo.com.au/sv3/sv3_1999_assignment2/node22.html), [12](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4620/2014fa/lectures/02trimesh1.pdf), [13](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-8-basic-shading/), ...

Comment: ... [14](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/253355228_fig1_Figure-8-Normal-Vector-of-Triangle-and-its-clustering), [15](http://www.f-lohmueller.de/pov_tut/a_geo/a_geo93e.htm), [16](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQa0ssA7IIA), [17](https://github.com/hughsk/triangle-normal/blob/master/index.js) ...
Every one of these (and doubtless countless others) answers the question—and some actually even have the desired C++/HLSL code. Seriously. This question has been so beaten to death, calling it "duplicate" is inadequate. "I can't seem to find the formula" my arse—you didn't _try_.

Comment: I'm surprised it got so many upvotes nontheless. ._.

Comment: @imallett i did try but as someone noticed the reason I wasn't getting any results because I was not following "Just for correctness, the label in the picture and question title should be "normal vector" instead of "normalized vector"."

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could easily find the normal by calculating two vectors, V1 = P2-P1, and V2 = P3-P1, and then find the cross product N = V1 x V2. Then you normalize N.  Depending on the ordering of the vertices (clockwise or counterclockwise) you will get a normal facing front or back.

You also need to make sure that three three points aren't aligned, if they are you have to pick another point.